# Archive 300Gb Binary

Tags: artifactory, nexus

At my company we have both a `Sonatype Nexus` and a `Jfrog artifactory` installation, which we normally use to manager our deliverables. Now, a project would require the archiving of a 300GB binary, which exceeds everything else we have by a factor of 100x.

My question is:
Are `nexus` or `artifactory` the correct way to handle this or are there better solutions?

I'm even concerned with the sizing of the partitions for temporary storage.

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype Nexus Repository has customers that deploy binaries substantially larger than that, you should be fine.

If you're concerned about sizing your partitions, consider using Repository Pro's blob store groups, which lets you add additional storage (at runtime if you need to). S3 is also a popular choice for binaries that size for obvious reasons, if that's an option.